# Cannot reconnect to gRPC server after client crashed

Tags: swift, rust, grpc, grpc-swift, rust-tonic

I did a lot of research but could not find a solution for my problem with gRPC:

**Summary;**
After my swift gRPC client application crashes, no gRPC client can connect to my gRPC Server anymore (see errors below)

**My Setup:**
I have a Swift frontend application and a Rust backend.
The rust backend runs a gRPC Server (tonic) https://github.com/hyperium/tonic to which a rust client (also tonic) and a Swift client (https://github.com/grpc/grpc-swift) can connect to.
After the Swift client crashes, none of the clients can connect anymore to the server.

The rust client reports:
`Error: Status { code: Cancelled, message: "h2 protocol error: protocol error: stream no longer needed" }`

The swift client reports:
`StreamClosed(streamID: HTTP2StreamID(1), errorCode: HTTP2ErrorCode<0x8 Cancel>, location: ".../swift-nio-http2/Sources/NIOHTTP2/HTTP2StreamChannel.swift:820")`

**What I've tried**
I setup a `http2 keepalive` in the server, but that didn't do anything.
I tried to reproduce the same effect by purposefully crashing the rust client - without success.

I'm not even sure wether to look at the swift-grpc and tonic libraries or grpc itself (for me it looks like the server closes the stream on purpose)..
Has anyone an idea what i could do to fix this?
Thanks in advance!